# Não consigo navegar em rotas de diferentes stacks com react navigation

Tags: react-native, stack, react-navigation

Eu tenho 3 arquivos de rotas.

1. Contem as rotas que o usuario pode acessar sem necessidade de estar logado, no meu caso so a tela de signin.

```html
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import SignInView from '../pages/SignIn';
import Loading from '../pages/Loading';

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
const AuthRoutes = () => (
    <AuthStack.Navigator>
        <AuthStack.Screen
            name='SignIn'
            component={SignInView}
        />
        <AuthStack.Screen
            name='Loading'
            component={Loading}
        />
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
);

export default AuthRoutes;
```

2. Rotas em que o usuario logado pode acessar. (TODAS AS OUTRAS)

```html
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Dashboard from '../pages/Dashboard';

const AppStack = createStackNavigator();

const AppRoutes = () => (
    <AppStack.Navigator>
        <AppStack.Screen
            name='Dashboard'
            component={Dashboard}
        />
    </AppStack.Navigator>
);

export default AppRoutes;
```

3. O que verifica se o usuario esta logado e redireciona para o arquivo correto de rotas.

```html
import React from 'react';

import AppRoutes from './app.routes';
import AuthRoutes from './auth.routes';
import { Logado } from '../services/apiUser';

const Routes = () => {
    //aqui vai o if com o retorno se esta ou nao logado se nao authroutes se sim approutes
    if(Logado){
        return <AppRoutes />;
    }else{
        return <AuthRoutes />;
    }
};

export default Routes;
```

Estou tentando chamar a dashboard e nao consigo

```html
const Dashboard = ({ navigation }) => {

  return (
    <Container>

      <ButtonDashboard onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AuthStack', {screen: 'Dashboard' })}>
        <ButtonTitle>Chamar Dashboar</ButtonTitle>
      </ButtonDashboard>

    </Container>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Recebo esse erro:

console.error: The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"neme":"AppRoutes", "params": {screen":"Dashboard"}} was not handled by any navigator

subi para o git para ficar mais facil me ajudar.
https://github.com/cirulei/vitrine

Answer (score -1):

Entendi seu problema. Você não pode, ou pelo menos não deveria, navegar de uma stack de rotas para outra.

Para trocar de stack, você terá de fazer assim, transforme sua variável `Logado` em um estado do React, pois ela muda quando o usuário faz login no seu app, quando o estado mudar o `if` que você fez para verificar se está logado executará novamente, e retornará outra stack de rotas.

Tomara que não fique complicado de entender,mas a ideia é essa, você não pode navegar para outra stack, você tem de definir em que stack está.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
  logado();
  }, []);
Algo assim ?

Comment: Tipo isso :const [user, setUser] = useState(); const userInfo = api.getUserInfo(); setUser(userInfo); export default user;